# SwiftUI - How to create a transition animation between views without impacting child view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation, swiftui-view

In SwiftUI, I've got an overarching view setup like this:

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    @State var index: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        if self.index == 0{
            FirstView(index: $index)
        }
        if self.index == 1 {
            SecondView(index: $index)
                .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                .animation(.easeIn)
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Where I have a button in FirstView that is equivalent of:

```
Button(action: {
   self.index = 1
}){
   Text("Change view")
}
```

This works fine and all is good, but I notice that, with this method, any views conditional on an if/else statement in the child views with a transition animation (i.e. SecondView in this case), *also have these animations applied*.

So, for example, if SecondView was as follows:

```
struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var index: Int
    @State var boolean: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if self.boolean == true {
                Text("Hello!")
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.boolean = true
            }){
                Text("change boolean")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the `Text("Hello")` would also have the `.transition(.move(edge: .bottom))` transition.

Is there any way to prevent this/a better way to create a transition animation from one view to another?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60785822/12299030?

Comment: Yeah I've seen the one liner  `.transition(AnyTransition.scale.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)))` but that doesn't seem to have quite the same effect as the two liner I have in my code, since it seems to only animate certain elements of the view, as opposed to having the entire view slide in -- perhaps I'll make a new post at some point and reference the linked post and the specific example of what I mean.