# How do I change the Sliding animation to something else?

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

Whenever I use the NavigationLink to open other Views, there is a default sliding animation which is very weird. How do I change it to something else?

```
                NavigationLink(
                destination: recipeView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(),
                isActive: $isActive1) {
                Button {
                    isActive1 = true
                    selectedTab = .recipe
                } label: {
                    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 4) {
                        if selectedTab == .recipe {
                            Rectangle()
                                .foregroundColor(selectedTab == .recipe ? Color("Orange") : Color.clear)
                                .frame(width: 90, height: 10)
                                .clipShape(BottomCornerRadius(radius: 5))
                                .offset(y: -11)
                        }
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "fork.knife")
                                .font(.system(size: 30))
                                .foregroundColor(selectedTab == .recipe ? Color("Orange") : Color("tabColor"))
                            Text("Recipe")
                                .font(.system(size: 17, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                                .foregroundColor(selectedTab == .recipe ? Color("Orange") : Color("tabColor"))
                        }
                        .background(
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 88)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .foregroundColor(selectedTab == .recipe ? Color("Orange").opacity(0.2) : Color.clear)
                                .offset(y: -7)
                        )
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/3)
                .offset(x: 10)
            }
                .animation(.spring())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to animate transition between views in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60784673/how-to-animate-transition-between-views-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of iOS navigation is 3 ways.

1: Push; which is the sliding animation you speak of.

2: modal sheet, which is a bottom sheet presented that is almost to the top

3: FullscreenCover, which is a bottom sheet that covers the screen.

Then you have other custom solutions, but not any good established ones for swiftUI yet.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-a-custom-transition is a semi transition.